# Adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to UILabel in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, tvos

I'm trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UILabel in tvOS.  It works well enough in the iOS version of the app - but no luck in the tvOS version.  The click just gets ignored!  I can work around it if I have to - but, for the sake of consistency (in code, if nothing else), I'd rather not have to:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *fxTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fxCheck:)];
    fxTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
#if TARGET_OS_TV
    fxTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
#endif
    [fxText addGestureRecognizer:fxTapGestureRecognizer];
    fxText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *musicGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(musicCheck:)];
    musicGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
#if TARGET_OS_TV
    musicGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
#endif
    [musicText addGestureRecognizer:musicGestureRecognizer];
    musicText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Has anyone got any experience of this problem?  Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: maybe it does not work because the fxText label is not focused? Also there is a difference between touching the remote and pressing the remotes touchpad until it clicks. You also can use pressesBegan on tvOS, here is an example in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html

Comment: Show more code please or send a link to your project.